# Не могу поставить свою иконку для приложения - Android Studio

Tags: android

Не могу поставить свою иконку в проект.

Никакие манипуляции с папкой res не помогают.

Пожалуйста, опишите подробно как это делать...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

Answer (score 2):

Иконки хранятся в папке mipmap как можно понять из манифеста:

```
<application
...
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
...
```

вот размеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того чтобы добавить свои иконки можно либо перейти в проводнике и добавить иконки с данными размерами, либо поступить проще и сделать все средствами Android Studio:

1. Правый клик на папке `app`
2. в появившемся меню `New->Image Asset`
3. В появившемся окне выбираем **Launcher Icons (Adaptive & Legacy)**
4. Выбираем картинку которая вам нужна в качестве иконки (должен быть svg для адаптивности)
5. в превью смотрим все ли красиво
6. нажимаем `next`

Вот как ниже на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и все. Вот есть [документация](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio) по данному вопросу, [туториал](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-update-the-launcher-icon-for-your-android-app--cms-30624) и [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXACM2e0ISE).  Так же вот есть [инструмент](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-update-the-launcher-icon-for-your-android-app--cms-30624) для генерации иконок, чтобы их добавить вручную.